# USB errors at startup

Tags: arch-linux, usb

Today I've installed Archlinux, and I get some errors (when I startup it) that I don't understand and don't know how to solve. Before it asks to login with my username and password, I get:

```
USB 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

when I write dmesg and press enter in the terminal, I get this about this usb device:

```
usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 3
usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

What does it mean? However, I can plug in my mouse.

Comment: Login and run `lsusb -v`, and look for devices 3 and 5.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `Device 005: IMC Networks - Couldn't open device, some information will be missing`, I can't see informations for device 3.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch maybe it's something related to webcam. I'm using i3wm and as it's so minimal I maybe don't have something installed, or probably I forgot to install some drivers?

Answer (score 1):

If you lookup what errorno 110 refers to, you get "Connection timed out":

```
[birdsnest ~][I]% grep 110 /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h 
#define ETIMEDOUT   110 /* Connection timed out */
```

So it's possible that you have a USB device that's not communicating correctly with the host.  If all of your USB devices are behaving as expected, and if they show up in `lsusb -v`, then I don't think you have anything to worry about.

Comment: `Device 005: IMC Networks - Couldn't open device, some information will be missing`, I think the camera isn't. When I try to open cheese, the application to test your camera and take videos/photos, I get this: `get chip id failed: -1 [13] - param: 4, val:0`

Comment: Sounds like you may have a faulty camera then, or perhaps your camera needs a proprietary driver.

Comment: Nono, lol. My camera was working when I was running Gnome. I have an intel video card, and yeah - I think I need a proprietary driver. Which one?

Comment: :shrug: who knows? You can probably figure it out by googling your model of camera.

Comment: If everything works as expected, I don't think you need to investigate that message any further.  It's not necessarily an indication that anything's wrong.